# Проверка статуса платежа easypay по id

Tags: python, http, https, requests, postman

Как сделать проверку статуса платежа easypay из исходных данных есть только id платежа использовать можно только библиотеку requests python.
https://partners.easypay.ua/ - на сайте внизу есть поле для проверки платежа, но мне не удалось туда постучаться через Postman

Comment: дайте пример номера платежа.

Comment: 766326823 - это номер (id) транзакции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://partners.easypay.ua/main/GetTransactionStatus'
data = {'inputData': '766326823'}
ans = requests.post(base_url, data).json()
print(ans)
```

> {'receiptStatus': 'Принят', 'receiptContent': '**КВИТАНЦIЯ № 18219-1056-74019534**
> ------------------------------------
> **(ІД операції): 766326823**
> Дата: 19.11.2019 03:31
> **Статус платежу: Прийнятий**
> ------------------------------------
> **Довідка за телефоном: 0-800-60-30-03**
> Дзвінок безкоштовний у межах України
> ------------------------------------
> Дякуємо, що обрали нас!'}

Comment: спасибо, мы не догадались использовать  https вместо http :D